# NetworkStream write not newlining if not thread slept

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networkstream, read-write

I have two pieces of software, one being a server and the other being the client interface.

In my server I am taking and handling request then returning a string through a method I wrote "reply"

```
    public static void reply(string buffer, NetworkStream stream)
    {
        stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buffer), 0, buffer.Length);
    }
```

the issue I am having is that for example if I were to do the below code

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
reply("SOME REPLY", stream);
}
```

the above code will write random newlined lines back to the client like this:

```
SOME REPLY
SOME REPLYSOME REPLY
SOME REPLY
SOME REPLYSOME REPLYSOME REPLY
SOME REPLYSOME REPLY
SOME REPLY
SOME REPLY
```

If I were to have put a 200ms Thread.Sleep call in the forloop it would have correctly newlined the responses.
On the client side the below code is how we're reading from the server and printing to console:

```
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        NetworkStream stream = endpoint.GetStream();
        int i;
        while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the client is not sending a newline, so the server basically has no clue where to put the newlines.
The fact that you're getting 'some' newlines, has to do with the way the stream is used, a NetworkStream will always read any data available when you call read, or wait until -some- data is available; there's no guarantee that what you receive is what you want.
You may read all the data from a stream on the server side in your application, then add a newline (Because of the Console.WriteLine call), and then continue on to read the next part of the message.

I suppose the easiest way to work around this is to simply change the `reply("SOME REPLY", stream);` call to `reply("SOME REPLY" + Environment.NewLine, stream);` and then change the `Console.WriteLine` call on the server-side to a simple `Console.Write` call.

A better, but slightly more complex way of handling fragmented or buffered messages would be to always send a 'byte-count' in front of your message from the client side, so that the server knows how many bytes to read before adding a newline:

Pseudocode:

```
Client => Send([number of bytes] + [data])
Server => Read([number of bytes] (Field))
Server => Read([data]) until received bytes count == [number of bytes]
```

Comment: This is where using a [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408(v=vs.110).aspx) can be useful. It does the writing of the leading length bytes for you.

Comment: Thank you, I actually  tried doing "\n" with no success but I do not believe that I switched to using "writ" over "writeline". Your fixed worked great.

Comment: If you're on windows, \n will need to be \r\n  - especially in .NET - See the Environment.NewLine property.

Answer (score 1):

The server isn't writing any newlines at all to the client, it's the client that inserts newlines after each block of text that it reads.

When something comes over the network stream, the client will read everything that is currently in the buffer, and write a newline after that. While processing that part of data, the server might have had time to write several pieces of text to the stream, so next time the client reads from the stream it can get more than one piece of text at once.

The only thing that separates the pieces of text coming from the server is a tiny gap of time, and the client didn't notice that as it was busy processing what it read before that. You could try to make the code notive those time gaps, but that's far from a robust solution.

If you want to separate the pieces of text you should send something in the actual stream that the client can reliably pick up. If you simply want line break between the text, then send the line breaks from the server, then the client can just write out what it gets without adding anything to it.